# How to use Google Map API in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

How to get started with CodeIgniter and Google Maps API.

Comment: Could you be more specific...What would you do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've got a CodeIgniter library specifically for this purpose. You can find more information about it here:

http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library

A few demos of what can be acheived using the library:

http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/

Give me a shout if you have any questions or need any help :)

Enjoy!

Comment: this is the ideal solution for your google map requirement with codeigniter

Answer (score 4):

CodeIgniter is a backend (server-side) framework. Google Maps API is a frontend (client-side) library. There isn't really any specialized knowledge you need to know about CodeIgniter to get Google Maps working, other than being able to [render a view](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html). The question is somewhat flawed in that you assume one depends on the other, when in reality, they are very much decoupled.

The question is similar to *how do i get jquery working with codeigniter?*...

Reading the CodeIgniter documentation would be a start to understanding how to echo HTML and JavaScript to the browser. The rest is almost entirely client-side JavaScript programming.